# Fill Value in a Column Based on multiple conditions in Another Columns (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a problem with deciding which value should I take for a new column in a dataframe that I will create. Here's the requirements:

1. The value should have length=17
2. The value should contains "MP" and the format is XXMPXXXXXXXXXXXX

And here's the data:

| Serial Number New | Serial Number + Keyword | Serial Number Old |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12MP3221156732243 | 12MP3221156732243 Restaurant | 12MP3221156732243 |
| 0 | Retail 12MP3251453730827 | 3251453730827 |
| 0 | K312MP3251773832657 | 3251773832657 |
| 11MP3221156732243 | 11MP3221156732243 | MP3221156732243 |
| 11MP3251156732267 | 0 | MP3251156732267 |

And here's the expected output:

| Serial Number New | Serial Number + Keyword | Serial Number Old | Serial Number Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12MP3221156732243 | 12MP3221156732243 Restaurant | 12MP3221156732243 | 12MP3221156732243 |
| 0 | Retail 12MP3251453730827 | 3251453730827 | 12MP3251453730827 |
| 0 | K312MP3251773832657 | 3251773832657 | 12MP3251773832657 |
| 11MP3221156732243 | 11MP3221156732243 | MP3221156732243 | 11MP3221156732243 |
| 11MP3251156732267 | 0 | MP3251156732267 | 11MP3251156732267 |

Does anyone know how to get the "Serial Number Final" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex for that `(..MP.{13})` (2 characters, MP, 13 characters):

```
df['Serial Number Final'] = df['Serial Number + Keyword'].str.extract(r'(..MP.{13})')
```

or, if the `x` can only be digits `\d\dMP\d{13}` (2 digits, MP, 13 digits):

```
df['Serial Number Final'] = df['Serial Number + Keyword'].str.extract(r'(\d\dMP\d{13})')
```

output:

```
   Serial Number New       Serial Number + Keyword  Serial Number Old Serial Number Final
0  12MP3221156732243  12MP3221156732243 Restaurant  12MP3221156732243   12MP3221156732243
1                  0      Retail 12MP3251453730827      3251453730827   12MP3251453730827
2                  0           K312MP3251773832657      3251773832657   12MP3251773832657
3  11MP3221156732243             11MP3221156732243    MP3221156732243   11MP3221156732243
```

##### use several columns (pick first match):

```
cols = ['Serial Number New', 'Serial Number + Keyword']

df['Serial Number Final'] = (df[cols]
 .apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(r'(\d\dMP\d{13})', expand=False))
 .bfill().iloc[:, 0]
)
```

output:

```
   Serial Number New       Serial Number + Keyword  Serial Number Old Serial Number Final
0  12MP3221156732243  12MP3221156732243 Restaurant  12MP3221156732243   12MP3221156732243
1                  0      Retail 12MP3251453730827      3251453730827   11MP3221156732243
2                  0           K312MP3251773832657      3251773832657   11MP3221156732243
3  11MP3221156732243             11MP3221156732243    MP3221156732243   11MP3221156732243
4  11MP3251156732267                             0    MP3251156732267   11MP3251156732267
```